# Angular 1 Sending Empty Payload on Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have a simple app that is posting an array of json to my API.  I have several other posts that are working successfully.

When I investigated I the network traffic I found that the POST was sending an empty array in the payload.

There is data in the variable when the request is made, I have verified this several times.

The Request:

```
  function postDemo(dp) {
            var x = dp;
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: BASE + 'acl/newDemo',
                    data: x,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    }

                })
                    .success(function (data, status) {

                        resolve(function () {
                            resolve(true);
                        });
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        reject(false);
                    });
            });

        }
```

the var x contains the array and is populated as I stated earlier.  The issue seems to be coming from this point.  The API is working correctly and is correct in not reading data because none is actually sent.

I have tried changing the content type and that does not make a difference.

The array is from $scope and outputs a complex object that has all values accounted for in the x variable when the POST is made.

This is what the browser is showing as the array value before it is posted:

> x = [
>           billingAddress: Object, 
>           billingDetails: Object, 
>           company: Object, 
>           importCompany: Object,
>           importProfile: Array[0]
>         ]

And a screen shot of the payload:

[image: Empty Payload]

Answer (score 0):

1) $http already return a promise, no need to use $q her.

2) Use this syntaxe : $http().then(sucess(), error() )  :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
function postDemo(dp) {
   return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: BASE + 'acl/newDemo',
          data: dp,
          crossDomain: true,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          }

      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          return true ;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
           return false ;
        });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the pointer but it does not change the problem or offer any solution.